# Shell script in Crontab is not working

Tags: sh, cron

I added jobs to `crontab`.

```
20 2 * * * sh /home/tomcat/bin/test3.sh
20 2 * * * sh /home/tomcat/bin/test.sh
```

I checked the permissions..

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      58 May 19 02:04 test3.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    3223 May 16 08:20 test.sh
```

And `test3.sh` is working from both command line and `crontab`.

```
#!/bin/sh


echo "test test test..." > /test3_sh.txt
```

But `test.sh` is not working from `crontab`. The code seems little complicated and messy but the purpose is simple. It retrieves data from MYSQL and send a mail via `sendmail`. When I run `test.sh` from command line it's working, but from `crontab` it's not.

```
#!/bin/sh


results=`mysql -N -h mysqlhost.com -u user -pmypassword -e "USE MYDB;
SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column4

FROM MYTABLE 
    ORDER BY REG_DT DESC 
    LIMIT 10;"`

IFS=$'
'

x="<style type="text/css">
table.gridtable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.gridtable th {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #dedede;
}
table.gridtable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style><table class="gridtable">
    <tr>
        <th>column 1</th><th>column 2</th><th>column 3</th><th>column 4</th>
    </tr>"
for i in $results; 
do
 x+="<tr>"
 x+="$i
"
 x+="</tr>"
done

x+="</table>"




cat - /home/tomcat/bin/test.log << EOF | sendmail -t -f test@test.com
to:test@test.com
from:test@test.com
subject:test mail
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<body>
<h3>my recent articles..</h3>
$x
<br><hr>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

I googled this problem and some said, some pahts and  ENV variables work differently from command line and crontab. But there's nothing like ENV variables in my sh.
There's a log path in my sh. It's little suspicious, but I'm not sure this could be a problem.

```
cat - /home/tomcat/bin/test.log << EOF | sendmail -t -f test@test.com
```

Comment: You are using Bash syntax in your script. The shebang line should thus be `#!/bin/bash` and you should not use `sh` to run the script. I don't think this alone will solve your problem, which is why I'm posting it as a comment. But you should definitely understand the difference between `sh` and `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a path. I added this paths to `crontab` and works well!

```
# path
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin/:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also navigate to the path and run the script as>>

20 2 * * * cd /home/tomcat/bin/ && sh test3.sh

It will work

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `sh` from the beginning of the command:

```
20 2 * * * /home/tomcat/bin/test3.sh
20 2 * * * /home/tomcat/bin/test.sh
```

Comment: referring this link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1795575, I created the output file, but still not working. * 4 * * * /home/tomcat/bin/test.sh >> /home/tomcat/bin/test_sh.log

Comment: Try: `20 2 * * * $HOME/.profile; /home/tomcat/bin/test.sh`

Comment: I suspect `sendmail` is not working in crontab. I'll test `sendmail ` alone in crontab.

Comment: not a good practice if you don't know what the default shell for cron is